# Dense subgroup of torsion elements

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, abelian-groups, topological-groups, torsion-groups

I need a help to find a counter example (or to prove) the following

Let $G$ be a compact abelian topological group. Assume there exists a dense subgroup $H\leq G$ such that every element of $H$ is of finite order then $G$ is a Lie group (equivalently, is it isomorphic to a direct product of a torus with a direct product of finite groups).

Note that the converse is true, every compact (abelian or non-abelian) Lie groups contains a dense subgroup of torsion elements

Comment: Hmm, your notion of a Lie group looks too wide for me. The subgroup $t(G)$ of all periodic elements is dense of any compact abelian topological group $G$ of the form $\Bbb T^\kappa\times \prod A_\alpha$, where $\{A_\alpha\}$ is a family of finite abelian group whose periods are bounded in common. Or you are asking whether such form of $G$ is necessary to have the subgroup $t(G)$ dense?

Comment: yes exactly, i asked whether such form is necessary to have the subgroup t(G) dense.

Comment: Just for general knowledge, if G is countably based profinite group (so no $S^1$ parts) and t(G) is dense in G then G is a direct product.

Comment: @Yanko what do you mean by "is a direct product"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a lot of counterexamples, but some efforts are needed in order to prove that a candidate group is indeed a counterexample. Also I may ask [my teacher](http://prima.lnu.edu.ua/faculty/mechmat/Departments/Topology/guran.html) about them. The first family consists of zero dimensional candidates, which are closed subgroups of the product $\prod A_\alpha$ of a family $\{A_\alpha\}$ of finite abelian group whose periods are bounded in common. Candidates of bigger dimensions constitute the second family is so-called *exotic tori*,  introduced by Dikranjan and Prodanov, I guess in [DP], that is compact abelian groups $G$ such that torsion part $t(G)$ has-non zero intersection with each non-zero closed subgroup of $G$. For us is essential that by Proposition 3 from [DP], torsion part of an exotic torus is dense in it. From the other hand, the motivation for introducing the exotic tori in [DP] was the fact that they are precisely the completions of the torsion minimal abelian groups. The structure of exotic tori has been described in detail in [DP]. In particular, Proposition 2.5* describes the structure of $n$-dimensional exotic tori as follows. A compact abelian group $G$ of dimensional $n$ is an exotic torus if and only if there is a representation of $G$ as a projective limit $$G=\lim_{\longleftarrow} G_m$$  such that $G_0=\Bbb T^n$, the continuous homomorphisms $\sigma_m$ in the projective system $$G_0\stackrel{\sigma_1}\longleftarrow G_1\stackrel{\sigma_2}\longleftarrow G_2\cdots \stackrel{\sigma_m} \longleftarrow G_m\longleftarrow\cdots$$ are epimorphisms and $\ker\sigma_m $ is a compact $p_m$-group for each natural $m$. Thus, according to Example 1* of [DP], for each natural $n$ there is a continuum non-isomorphic connected $n$-dimensional exotic tori (so here **we have continuum many connected counterexamples**). For more details on exotic tore see [DP] or [DPS]. See also [CD], in particular, Theorem 4.1 and Remark 4.2(c). Also you can google for exotic torus Prodanov Dikranjan.

*References*

[CD] W. W. Comfort, Dikran Dikranjan, *[On the poset of totally dense subgroups of compact groups](http://topology.auburn.edu/tp/reprints/v24/tp24206.pdf)*, Topology Proceedings, **24**, Summer 1999, 103–127.

[DP] D. Dikranjan, I. Prodanov, *[A class of compact Abelian groups](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-NB9TVigIcreHNWSkJ4a2VJaGc/view?usp=drive_web)*, Annuaire Univ. Soﬁa, Fac. Math. Méc. **70** (1975/76), 191–206.

[DPS] D. Dikranjan, I. Prodanov, L. Stoyanov, *[Topological groups. Characters, dualities and minimal group topologies](https://mega.nz/#!A5hEHTDR!MeBaxbJQ9-gvEX6hSDBXuckswMGTWuryUFKSf5xpopo)*, Marcel Dekker, Inc., New York, 1990.

Comment: I might have a use of the article of DP, if you still have it then it would be nice if you can scan it for me.

Comment: @yanko OK, if this is urgent then I can do this. If not then I can assign this task to the student and I hope it will be done in a pair of weeks from now (such a long delay is because there are vacations now, and it is not so easy for me to catch the student).

Comment: That's fine, I'll wait. Thanks

Comment: @yanko Yesterday I gave the paper to the student. He said that he'll start to scan it next week.

Comment: @yanko At last I received the link to the scanned paper (added to the references).